# log publish/unpublish actions

Tags: nodes

For certain node types I want to log/track each time the publish status changes from published to unpublised and from unpublished to published. I am aware I could do this with rules and write log entries into the standard log, but I don't think this is a good solution.
I prefer to have a specific logtable for that, so that I can export it and that I can also show the history in a special tab of the node.

I was doing now some research, but could not find anything in this direction.

Is there a module I have not seen and which would be the solution?

If not, what would be the best approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only module I can think of is [Workbench Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation). It may be much too large and complex for your needs, but within the node's "Moderate" tab, it provides a list of all editing actions including the change of the node's status.

[Screenshot](https://www.drupal.org/files/images/workbench-moderation-screenshot.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Event Log](https://www.drupal.org/project/event_log) module. Install the event_log_node sub module and then you create a view of type 'Logged Events' and add relationships to the author and node, or visit admin/reports/events

It does not provide a publish/unpublish logging action because there is no such hook, so you should just replace the whole of the function event_log_node_update($node) function in the event_log_node.module with this one here which adds that functionality:

```
function event_log_node_update($node) {
  $log = array(
    'type' => 'node',
    'operation' => 'update',
    'description' => t('%type: %title', array(
      '%type' => $node->type,
      '%title' => $node->title
    )),
    'ref_numeric' => $node->nid,
    'info' => $node->original,
  );
  event_log_insert($log);

  if ($node->original->status == 0 && $node->status == 1) {
    //publish event
    $log = array(
      'type' => 'node',
      'operation' => 'publish',
      'description' => t('%type: %title', array(
        '%type' => $node->type,
        '%title' => $node->title
      )),
      'ref_numeric' => $node->nid,
      'info' => $node->original,
    );
    event_log_insert($log);
  }
  elseif ($node->original->status == 1 && $node->status == 0){
    // unpublish event
    $log = array(
      'type' => 'node',
      'operation' => 'unpublish',
      'description' => t('%type: %title', array(
        '%type' => $node->type,
        '%title' => $node->title
      )),
      'ref_numeric' => $node->nid,
      'info' => $node->original,
    );
    event_log_insert($log);
  }
}
```

You also might want to delete the function in that same file

```
function event_log_node_init()
```

as it adds a log entry for every view and that will clutter up the log. If you do clear the cache.

Comment: Thanks, taht's great. I did not find this module and thanks for the code. I will try it. best regards